# ¿Cómo cambiar ::after y ::before de un elemento con Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Necesito cambiar el atributo **content** de los pseudo elementos after y before del siguiente elemento del HTML **sin utilizar librerías como jQuery**. Si hiciera algo similar con CSS sería algo como esto:

```
#text::before{background:red;display:block,content:"HolaMundo";}
#text::after{background:blue;color:red,font-size:100px;}
```

¿Cuál sería la manera de hacerlo con Javascript?

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
text...
```

Comment: ¿Por qué lo estás pensando con `::after` y `::before` en vez de simplemente insertar elementos/nodos antes y después de `#text`?

Comment: Realmente es por necedad; hice las pruebas con css y funciona pero quiero aprender algo nuevo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes preparar ::after y ::before para que carguen por defecto el contenido de un atributo.

En el ejemplo he usado el atributo "title":

```
#text::after{
  content: attr(title);
}
```

Y después lo actualizar con Javascript.

```
document.querySelector("#text").setAttribute("title" , "Nuevo texto")
```

o

```
document.querySelector("#text").title = "Nuevo texto";
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, creo que `title` no es la mejor elección porque tiene efectos colaterales (el tooltip sobre el elemento) lo cual puede no ser deseado y como esta técnica funciona con cualquier otro atributo -incluso uno no standard- tal vez, seria mejor usar un `data-*`. Salu2

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esto pude lograr lo que me propuse.

Answer (score 3):

Desafortunadamente, no es posible seleccionar ni cambiar un psuedo elemento directamente con JavaScript.  Sin embargo, se puede hacer con una combinación de CSS y JavaScript.  Por ejemplo, podrías crear algunas clases con diferentes contenidos en el psuedo elemento, y usar JavaScript para cambiar la clase:

CSS:

```
#text::before {
    content: "HolaMundo";
}

#text.nombre {
    content: "Mi nombre es...";
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// Decir nombre
document.querySelector("#text").classList.add("nombre");

// Decir HolaMundo
document.querySelector("#text").classList.remove("nombre");
```

Answer (score 3):

Como ya dijeron no se puede cambiar los pseudo elemento ya que no pertenece al DOM.

En el siguiente código *simulo* con la ayuda de [selectores de atributo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo) y un poquito de `js` como se podría realizar:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('texto');

function changeToAfter(id) {
  
  // Creamos el atributo data-class con el contenido after
  document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('data-class', 'after');
}

function changeToBefore(id){

  // Creamos el atributo data-class con el contenido before
  document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('data-class', 'before'); 
}

document.getElementById('after').onclick = function() {
  
    changeToAfter(text.id);
};

document.getElementById('before').onclick = function() {
  
    changeToBefore(text.id);
};
```

```css
[data-class=before]::before{
  background: red;
  content: 'Hello ';
  background: red;
}

[data-class=after]::after {
  content: ' world!';
  background: pink;
}

/* solo para dar un poooco de estilo a los botones que están feísimos */
button {
  outline: 0; 
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

button:hover {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<p id="texto"> wonderful </p> 

<!-- Solo para simulación -->
<button id="before">Before</button> 
<button id="after">After</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Algo que si puedes hacer es crear un elemento `<style id="myStyle">` dentro del cual puedas agregar contenido en medio de la ejecucion y asi tener un control un poco mayor de la situación. Lo he utilizado y funciona de lo mejor.